# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions

Tags: keras

I have tried the following example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import *  
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.random((30,50,50,3))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(30,1))

model = Sequential()    

#start from the first hidden layer, since the input is not         actually a layer   
#but inform the shape of the input, with 3 elements.    
model.add(Dense(units=4,input_shape=(3,))) #hidden layer 1    with input

#further layers:    
model.add(Dense(units=4)) #hidden layer 2
model.add(Dense(units=1)) #output layer

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
           optimizer='adam',
           metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
       epochs=20,
       batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

I get this error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 50, 50, 3).

Thus, I changed the input_shape as follows:

```
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import *  
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.random((30,50,50,3))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(30,1))

model = Sequential()    

#start from the first hidden layer, since the input is not         actually a layer   
#but inform the shape of the input, with 3 elements.    
model.add(Dense(units=4,input_shape=(50,50,3))) #hidden layer 1    with input

#further layers:    
model.add(Dense(units=4)) #hidden layer 2
model.add(Dense(units=1)) #output layer

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
           optimizer='adam',
           metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
       epochs=20,
       batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

But now I get this error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1)

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the output shape of **the last dense layer**. You can use **model.summary()** to see the output shape of each layer.

> your output shape is (None,50,50,1),but to match with your y_train
>   shape it should be in (None,1) shape.

So i suggest you to add a **flattern layer** before the last dense layer.Plese refer this [link](https://keras.io/layers/core/) for the definition of flattern layer in keras.

This is how your model code should looks like

```
model.add(Dense(units=4,input_shape=(50,50,3),name="d1")) #hidden layer 1    with input  
model.add(Dense(units=4,name="d2")) #hidden layer 2
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1,name="d3")) #output layer

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
           optimizer='adam',
           metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Futher more use name for your layers it will be easy for you to understand where the problem is.good luck ;-)